# C# Filtering employee ID's from a list to modify a query

Tags: c#, linq

Learning C# here. I have a monthly process form whereby one can select to process salaries for all employees or select the employees to process for using radio buttons (SAP B1 form using screenpainter).

One is able to open a form to select employees and the employee ID's are sent to this monthly process form and are stored in a list.

```
//Method to retrieve string values from child form
public void GetFilteredIds(List<string> idValues)
{
    List<string> employeeIDs = new List<string>();

    employeeIDs = idValues;
}
```

I wanted to filter this query on the monthly process form that selects **ALL** emp IDs

```
//Query database
var salaryFitments = salaryFitmentService.GetAllSalaryFitments();

var employeeIdList = (from sf in salaryFitments select sf.U_Employee_ID).Distinct();
```

such that I have something similar to this:

```
var k = from id in employeeIdList
           where employeeIDs.Contains(id)
           select id;
```

How do I write my code such that just before processing (hitting a process button), I have an if statement to check if its a monthly process for all or just a few selected

```
if (_selectedEmployees.Selected == true)
{
   ...code to write
}
else
{
   ...code to write
}
```

_selectedEmployees refers to `private SAPbouiCOM.OptionBtn _selectedEmployees;`

Just before processing

```
if (employeeIdList.Any())
            {  ............
```

I hope my question is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're after, but would this help:

```
// Code to see if the 'all employees' radiobutton is selected.

var k = from id in employeeIdList
        where AllSelected || employeeIDs.Contains(id)
        select id;
```

You wouldn't have to duplicate your query then.